# Add Rich text column to the Blog Post comment (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: column, xslt, blog, rich-text

I am trying to customize the Blog post comments in SharePoint 2013 by adding a new custom column using RichText (called `RTBody`) and hiding the old one called `Body` in several pages, such as `Post.aspx` and in views like `Allcomments.aspx`.

There is no problem for the views of the "Comments" Webpart but I cannot integrate the new column in the main page and `post.aspx`.

Moreover the textbox for adding new comments disappear when I load a new customized `customblog.xsl` file as described in the following procedure:
[Customizing the blog posts in a SharePoint blog template](http://heatherwaterman.com/2011/05/customizing-the-blog-posts-in-a-sharepoint-blog-template/)
[image]

The problem is to show ViewFields section of the Comments Webpart to `Post.aspx` page.
I can also modify `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\BlogSiteTemplate\Comments\schema.xml` but I am not sure if it helps.

Do you have an idea of the procedure?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I found a way to display the Rich Text comments, the column need to be created in the list (List Settings / Columns / Create column) and not in site settings / site columns / create. The newly created column belongs to the list, not to the comment content type.

Comment: I am trying to connect a custom column from the Comments Webpart to the Posts Webpart with this functionality:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-data-in-Web-Parts-54a36fda-019c-49b3-ad33-0cd94bf70c1e?CorrelationId=523c513e-b7b4-41f9-ae1c-1e92dad5deeb&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US. Unfortunately the post shows an Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, and it works perfectly

http://spjsblog.com/commentbox-for-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

This is a third party tailored made solution, exactly what I was looking for:

http://spjsblog.com/commentbox-for-sharepoint/

I hope it can help somebody else !!